# ROO Annotations with SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How can I use/enable ROO annotations (I beleive it's using AspectJ?) inside a STS project?

For example, I want to use :
@RooJavaBean for generating the getter/setter methods automagically.

(Maven is also "installed" in the project)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Roo project and these annotations are handled for you automatically.  You can do this through the New Roo project wizard:

```
File -> New... -> Spring Roo Project
```

Comment: Although it is possible to use Roo on existing projects, it is difficult to convert an existing class to become a Roo entity class and I'd recommend against it.  I'd recommend using Roo to introduce new entities into an existing project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ROO shell for this and just follow the hints.

For example, to create a java bean with ROO annotations:

```
roo> entity --class ~.User --testAutomatically
roo> field string --fieldName name --notNull
```